# Facebook share with custom image single page app

Tags: facebook, share

Hey guys so I want to share a link to facebook and have an image preview. But heres the catch I know that facebook recently updated their api and that everyone is using meta tags like so for the images to be used in facebook like so: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">` the problem is I have a single page application using vuejs and express and I want a user to be able to share a link to my website but have their personal image preview for their post so it cant just be a generic picture in the meta tag.
this tag works to get the user to the page but no mater what I pass into it I cannot seem to get my dynamic picture show up.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=myWebsiteUrl" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

I know you used to be able to do

```
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=myWebsiteUrl&p[images][0]=myImagePath" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

but this no longer works any help would be great.

Comment: see duplicate thread. the sharer does not accept custom params since many years, that's not a recent change.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the root of my question. How do I share a link with a user picked image on a single page application?

Comment: you would need to upload the picture to your server first, and then you would need to create a permalink that includes that picture as og:image - without javascript. there is a link to prerender.io in the answer of the duplicate question, you can also google for "server side rendering", for example.

Comment: Im building my app with webpack. Could you show me an example of how you would do that? Thanks.

Comment: just google for SSR, it is a well known thing. also take a look at prerender.io.

Comment: Hey I have a solution using handlebars that worked quite well can you please allow me to post the answer? Thank you